# How to display "META" array in register_taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, api, json

How do I get the "META" field to go off "META: []" for something filled in? I am using this code:

```
register_taxonomy( 'job_listing_category', 'job_listing', [
            'labels' => [
                'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'menu_name'         => _x( 'Categories', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'search_items'      => _x( 'Search Categories', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'all_items'         => _x( 'All Categories', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'parent_item'       => _x( 'Parent Category', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Category:', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'edit_item'         => _x( 'Edit Category', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'update_item'       => _x( 'Update Category', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'add_new_item'      => _x( 'Add New Category', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
                'new_item_name'     => _x( 'New Category Name', 'Category taxonomy labels', 'my-listing' ),
            ],
            'rewrite' => [
                'slug' => $permalink_structure['category_base'],
                'with_front'   => false,
                'hierarchical' => false,
            ],
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_tagcloud'         => false,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_in_rest'          => true,
        ] );
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What meta field?

Comment: Sorry for this, 'META' in JSON link.

[EXAMPLE](https://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-json/wp/v2/job_listing)
You can see "meta: [ ]"

Answer (score 0):

You could get array from json like below:

```
$request = wp_remote_get( 'https://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-json/wp/v2/job_listing' );
if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
    return false; // Bail early
}
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$data = json_decode( $body );
if( ! empty( $data ) ) {

    foreach($data  as $subdata){
        print_r($subdata->meta);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for where can I put this code?

Comment: where you want to display the code i have put it in functions.php file